# Select parents and children from one table in the correct order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has hierarchical data with parent and child records. I want to select them in the correct order no matter which order the data recorded in the table using MySql. How to list the following data in below example using a single query?

Ex: Table

```
ID | Title | Parent
1  | A     | 0
2  | B     | 1
3  | C     | 1
4  | D     | 0
5  | E     | 4
6  | F     | 4
7  | G     | 0
8  | H     | 7
9  | I     | 1
10 | J     | 4
```

Into..

```
ID | Title | Parent
1  | A     | 0
2  | B     | 1
3  | C     | 1
9  | I     | 1
4  | D     | 0
5  | E     | 4
6  | F     | 4
10 | J     | 4
7  | G     | 0
8  | H     | 7
```

Comment: you fetch the second table on what basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.Parent = 0 THEN t.ID ELSE t.Parent END,
         t.ID
```

**Note:** This will work for the data you provided, it won't work for more then 1 level of hierarchy !

Comment: Yes it is single level hierarchy. Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you looking for ?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY IF(Parent = 0 ,id,Parent);
```

Comment: @ Error404 - and after the comment i have change my answer